# TFT screen shield worked and quickly quit

Tags: arduino, hardware

I bought an Arduino Uno board and the Elegoo 2.8" TFT Shield. I plugged them together. It just worked. Examples from Elegoo including graphicstest and displaystring worked great. Then I tried another example, also from Elegoo, tftpaintshield. It failed to recognize the driver, which came back with an ID of 101. I found the following hack in graphicstest, which just forces the issue:

```cpp
uint16_t identifier = tft.readID();
identifier=0x9341;

...

} else if(identifier == 0x9341) {
Serial.println(F("Found ILI9341 LCD driver"));
```

Tried applying that to tftpaintshield. When I ran it it got as far as printing its introductory string, "Paint!"… And then nothing else happened. No graphics.

Went back to the graphics-only examples that had worked before, and graphicstest now displays all the normal bench-marking output in the serial window, but NO GRAPHICS. The display screen remains white.

Could that hack have broken something?

**Things tried:**

- Power cycling/disconnecting the Arduino board
- Pressing reset on the Arduino board
- Stopping and restarting the Arduino programming interface app.

Nothing helps.
There was no unplugging of the shield from the Arduino board, no funny touching of electronics that would be likely to cause any harm.

Any ideas? Do I have a defective part that failed rapidly under test?

Comment: there is nothing `IoT` specific in your post ... it is like asking how to repair a garden rake at a gardening website

Comment: This is marginally more suitable for [electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Did it smell bad at the time? Are there any traces of anything burned or otherwise damaged in the PCB? Can you see if the backlight is on? Can you see anything on the screen if you shine bright light at it while running one of the original samples which worked?